# F# Marshal.SizeOf exception involving an array of enums within a struct

Tags: struct, enums, f#, marshalling, sizeof

I am encountering a runtime exception involving `Marshal.SizeOf` that I do not understand. After stripping out lots of code, I have come up with a small example that demonstrates the issue:

```
#nowarn "9"

open System.Runtime.InteropServices

type Gray = | Black = 0 | Gray = 1 | White = 2

[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)>]
type GrayStruct =
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)>]
    val mutable Triple: Gray[]

type Color = | Red = 0 | Green = 1 | Blue = 2

[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)>]
type ColorStruct =
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)>]
    val mutable Triple: Color[]

let colorStructToUnit (colorStruct: ColorStruct) = ()

printfn "%A" (Marshal.SizeOf(typeof<GrayStruct>))
printfn "%A" (Marshal.SizeOf(typeof<ColorStruct>))
```

Running this sample with fsi.exe (version 4.1) results in:

```
12
System.ArgumentException: Type 'FSI_0001+ColorStruct' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOfHelper(Type t, Boolean throwIfNotMarshalable)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(Type t)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0001>.$FSI_0001.main@() in 
C:\f#\Example\example.fsx:line 21
Stopped due to error
```

Note the similarity between `GrayStruct` and `ColorStruct`, yet `Marshal.SizeOf` chokes on `ColorStruct`. `Marshal.SizeOf` appears to throw an exception because of the existence of the `colorStructToUnit` function. If that function is removed, the output becomes:

```
12
12
```

Also, if I keep the `colorStructToUnit` function, but replace:

```
    val mutable Triple: Color[]
```

with:

```
    val mutable Triple: int[]
```

then the output also becomes:

```
12
12
```

Thanks for any insight you may have into this issue.

---

Note that I am experiencing this problem in a much larger codebase that is trying to interface with a legacy DLL via PInvoke. This problem appears to only affect arrays of enums within structs. One workaround would be to marshal the underlying types (i.e., `int[]` instead of `Color[]`) and then cast those values into enums, but that solution requires multiple definitions of almost identical structs. Is there a more elegant way to overcome this problem?

Comment: If you place the function in a module (e.g. `module ColorStruct`) it works the same as if the function was not there at all.

Comment: This reproduces for me in F# Interactive, but works perfectly fine if I compile to `exe` and run. Looks like it's just an artifact of FSI.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: It works when I compile it too. Does this mean this is a bug in FSI?

Comment: @CaringDev: It also works if I move the `colorStructToUnit` inside `ColorStruct` as a member function.

Comment: Yes, I think it's FSI's fault - though not necessarily a bug, maybe just an unexpected consequence of some seemingly benign program restructuring. Though I was unable to determine what it is so far.

Comment: I've been trying to work my way backwards from [the implementation of Marshal.SizeOf](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/44f57065649af5f8bcbb7c71d827221a7bc1bf7a/src/vm/marshalnative.cpp#L263) but all I can currently say is that [IsStructMarshalable](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/44f57065649af5f8bcbb7c71d827221a7bc1bf7a/src/vm/fieldmarshaler.cpp#L1176) returns `TRUE` for one but `FALSE` for the other. My C++ capabilities end here.